# How to raise an event after few seconds of http request using Observables without cancelling the request in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, http, post, timeout, observable

I have a http request and I want to show alert or console after few seconds(say 5sec, if there is no response from service till that time), without cancelling the request. Means request should be in progress just a console should come.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer just before you send a http request and on 5 secs or so you can check the state of the application i.e if the response is received or not.

A small plunker demonstrating use of Timer:

> http://embed.plnkr.co/HaTd8q/

If your response is still not there you can display message else you can clear out the messages and show the response.

via Observable

```
timer = Observable.timer(initialDelay, period);

timer.subscribe(tick => {
   // Your API call, which will be performed every period so you might want to unsuscribe
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but is there any operator in Observable which can help me in this. Or all the timer related operator will cancel my request?

Comment: Observable have a method named timer that you can use this way (but I never used it)... just updated the answer with example.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Using timer the actual call is happening after defined amount of seconds, but what I want is to show a message after 5 sec if there is no response from service till that time.